# Invalid values from Mt. Gox websockets API

Tags: c++, websocket, mtgox

I'm trying to use websockets Mt. Gox API to get the recent quotes for the USD currency. So, i write the following code that connects to "ws://websocket.mtgox.com:80/mtgox" and listens for the messages.

```
#include <websocketpp/config/asio_no_tls_client.hpp>
#include <websocketpp/client.hpp>

#include <boost/property_tree/json_parser.hpp>

#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

typedef websocketpp::client<websocketpp::config::asio_client> websocket_client_t;
typedef websocketpp::config::asio_client::message_type::ptr websocket_message_ptr_t;

const std::string WEBSOCKET_MTGOX_API_BASE_URL = "ws://websocket.mtgox.com:80/mtgox";
const std::string ORIGIN_HEADER_VALUE = "http://www.example.com";
const std::string TICKER_CHANNEL_ID = "d5f06780-30a8-4a48-a2f8-7ed181b4a13f";

boost::property_tree::ptree construct_pt_from_string(const std::string& json_string)
{
    boost::property_tree::ptree pt;
    std::stringstream json_isstr;
    json_isstr << json_string;

    boost::property_tree::read_json(json_isstr, pt);

    return pt;
}

bool is_ticker_channel(const boost::property_tree::ptree& pt)
{
    try
    {
        const std::string& channel_id = pt.get<std::string>("channel");
        if (channel_id != TICKER_CHANNEL_ID)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    catch (const boost::property_tree::ptree_error& ex)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

void parse_message(const std::string& message)
{
    boost::property_tree::ptree message_pt;
    try
    {
        message_pt = construct_pt_from_string(message);
    }
    catch (const boost::property_tree::json_parser_error& ex)
    {
        std::cerr << "An error occurred while parsing message: " << ex.what() << '\n';
        return;
    }

    if (!is_ticker_channel(message_pt))
    {
        return;
    }

    try
    {
        const std::string& currency = message_pt.get<std::string>("ticker.buy.currency");
        double buy = message_pt.get<double>("ticker.buy.value");
        double sell = message_pt.get<double>("ticker.sell.value");

        std::cout << "Currency: " << currency << " | Buy: " << buy << " | Sell: " << sell << '\n';
    }
    catch (const boost::property_tree::ptree_error& ex)
    {
        std::cerr << "An error occurred while parsing message: " << ex.what() << '\n';
        return;
    }
}

void on_websocket_open(websocketpp::connection_hdl hdl)
{
    std::cout << "WebSocket successfully opened \n";
}

void on_websocket_close(websocketpp::connection_hdl hdl)
{
    std::cout << "WebSocket closed \n";
}

void on_websocket_message(websocket_client_t* c, websocketpp::connection_hdl hdl, websocket_message_ptr_t msg)
{
    const std::string& message = msg->get_payload();
    parse_message(message);
}

int main()
{
    try
    {
        websocket_client_t c;

        c.init_asio();

        c.set_open_handler(on_websocket_open);
        c.set_close_handler(on_websocket_close);
        c.set_message_handler(
            websocketpp::lib::bind(
                &on_websocket_message
                , &c
                , websocketpp::lib::placeholders::_1
                , websocketpp::lib::placeholders::_2
            )
        );

        websocketpp::lib::error_code error_code;
        websocket_client_t::connection_ptr con = c.get_connection(WEBSOCKET_MTGOX_API_BASE_URL + "?Currency=USD", error_code);
        if (error_code)
        {
            std::cerr << "An error occurred while using function get_connection: " << error_code.message() << '\n';
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        con->replace_header("Origin", ORIGIN_HEADER_VALUE);

        c.connect(con);

        c.run();
    }
    catch (const std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
    catch (const websocketpp::lib::error_code& e)
    {
        std::cout << e.message() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

When a message with channel == "d5f06780-30a8-4a48-a2f8-7ed181b4a13f" (ticker channel) received, i'm trying to parse it and get the ticker.buy.value and ticker.sell.value. But the values are far from their analogues from this statistics - http://bitcoincharts.com/markets/currency/USD.html (low and high matches only). What am I doing wrong? Maybe another channel, server, json field from message or smth else?

Comment: I've been following in your footsteps ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20055987/mtgox-api-and-websocketpp?rq=1 ) 

As far as I can see, the bitcoincharts url prices are statistics gathered from the real time series values coming from your websocket connection. Current ask and bid prices can be gathered from the depth.BTCUSD channel. Trades show you the actual buy and sell transactions. Ticker is an average calculated by mtgox itself. It is easy to manipulate, so better stick to making your own candle data using trades channel in my opinion. And thanks for the code.